# How to include HTML on PHP function, after to be rendered?

Tags: php, html, function, class

I need to include html code inside a php function,after to use the function in another html code.
The HTML code should be in another file, i want to call that code in specified row in another file.

**HTML code**

```
<span>
<?php
$register_date = new Moment\Moment($u->get("date"), date_default_timezone_get());
$register_date->setTimezone($AuthUser->get("preferences.timezone"));
$format = $AuthUser->get("preferences.dateformat");
if (!$format) {
$format = "Y-m-d";
}
?>
 <?= __("Register date: %s", $register_date->format($format)) ?>
</span>
```

**The function**

```
function thefunction (){
//the html code here
}
```

**The code i want to include the function**

```
<?php if ($u->get("expire_date") < "2050"): ?>
<div class="meta">

<?php ?>
function thefunction ()//The function
?>

</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Normal code without the function**

```
<?php if ($u->get("expire_date") < "2050"): ?>
<div class="meta">

<span>
<?php
$register_date = new Moment\Moment($u->get("date"), date_default_timezone_get());
$register_date->setTimezone($AuthUser->get("preferences.timezone"));
$format = $AuthUser->get("preferences.dateformat");
if (!$format) {
$format = "Y-m-d";
}
?>
 <?= __("Register date: %s", $register_date->format($format)) ?>
</span>

</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: If you want to call a function that is in another file, then you must [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (or require) the other file.

Comment: if you want a function to print some ready made HTML, you could call [`readfile($myHtmlFileAndPath);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) or use just use [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) to mix HTML and variables.

Comment: Maybe not the best way to divide logic and presentation, but just paste that code into the function.  You'll need to pass in `$u` and `$AuthUser`: `function thefunction ($u, $AuthUser)` and call `thefunction ($u, $AuthUser);`

Answer (score 0):

One (more elegant) approach, all in php, would be:

```
<?php
    //php code
    function sayHello (){
        echo '<p>Hello</p>';
    }
    sayHello();
    sayHello();
?>
```

Another approach would be:

```
<?php
//php code
function sayHello(){ //leave that bracket open ?>

    <!--this is html but you're still inside the function. this won't be printed until you call the function-->
    <p>Hello</p>

<?php } //function ends here ?>
```

Then, in any point:

```
<?php sayHello(); ?>
```

and your html will be printed